# Sencha Touch ListPaging TotalCount not being set

Tags: sencha-touch

Using Sencha Touch 2.3.1a.  I have a list which uses ListPaging:

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    itemId: 'passDownList',
    store: 'PassDownEntrysStore',
    plugins: 
    [
        {
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging: true
        }
    ],
    grouped : true,
    itemTpl: '<div class="list-item-title">{time}</div><div class="list-item-narrative">{firstName} {lastName}</div>',
    selectedCls: 'list-item-module',
    itemCls: 'list-item-custom',
    onItemDisclosure: true,
}
```

Using the following Store Proxy settings:

```
proxy: 
{
    type: 'ajax',
    actionMethods: 
    {
        read   : 'POST'
    },
    extraParams :
    {
    },
    url: App.config.Config.baseURL() + 'subscriptions/',
    reader: 
    {
        type: 'json',
        totalProperty: 'totalCount',
        //totalCount: 'totalCount',
        //total: 'totalCount',
        rootProperty: 'Data.items',
        successProperty: 'success'
    }
}
```

This is the data returned from the server:

[image: Service return data]

I've tried all three reader settings:

```
totalProperty: 'totalCount',
//totalCount: 'totalCount',
//total: 'totalCount',
```

and totalCount is always 'undefined'.  I tried to add a load event on the store to update the total count:

```
load: function(records, successful, operation, eOpts)
{
    var data = JSON.parse(eOpts._response.responseText);

    this.setTotalCount(data.Data.totalCount);
    console.log('load call total: ' + this.getTotalCount());
}
```

which sets it. But when i pull the list to show more entries and inspect the total count in the load event its been reset to 'undefined' again.
The reason why i want this to work is so it shows the "No More Records"

**Update: 6/18/2014:**
Well setting it on the load worked for me:

```
load: function(records, successful, operation, eOpts)
{
var data = JSON.parse(eOpts._response.responseText);

this.setTotalCount(data.Data.totalCount);
console.log('load call total: ' + this.getTotalCount());
}
```

This why it keeps setting the totals.  I still dont understand why it comes back undefined though so something is missing/bug.  But for now this solves my problem with paging

Answer (score 0):

Actually setting `totalProperty: 'count'` at the reader config worked for me, while interacting with the REST api, but your update is also working too.

example of proxy settings (btw it's not in the store configs, but in the model)

```
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : 'https://*******.info/api/v3/posts/',
        withCredentials: false,
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            rootProperty : 'results',
            totalProperty : 'count'

        }
        //format  :'json'
    }
```

Comment: I have ver 2.3.1a i'm not a subscriber so cant download 2.3.2 until it becomes available.  I will have to wait till then.  Hopefully its just a bug.  Thanks

Comment: I have 2.3.1 too, and it's (the totalProperty param) working as expected. One difference from your code - i'm using the 'count' parameter instead of 'totalCount' from the server response.. Don't know if it matters.

Comment: I just tried using count also like: count: 'totalCount' and nothing

Comment: Can you post an example of your store to see